# how to order asc/dsc with lambda or linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

how to order descending an `IEnumerable<T>` with linq or lambda ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Enumerable.OrderByDescending
```

if the problem was that you wanted descending and not ascending

Answer (score 5):

If you mean a non-generic `IEnumerable`, you should use `Cast` or `OfType` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` first, then you can use the normal `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` calls.

For example:

```
IEnumerable test = new string[] { "abc", "x", "y", "def" };
IEnumerable<string> orderedByLength = test.Cast<string>()
                                          .OrderBy(x => x.Length);
```

You can also do this by explicitly stating the type in a query expression:

```
IEnumerable<string> orderedByLength = from string x in test
                                      orderby x.Length
                                      select x;
```

EDIT: Now that the question has been clarified, the query expression form is:

```
var query = from value in collection
            orderby value.SomeProperty descending
            select value;
```

Comment: sorry I actually meant Generic IEnumerable<T>, and the most important thing is how to do it descending

Comment: With the "orderby x.Length" or "orderby x.Length descending" to answer the title but not the question body :)

Comment: @Omu: Please be more careful when writing questions. If you're unclear, it wastes both our time and yours.

Answer (score 4):

If your talking about a generic IEnumerable, below is a trimmed down example of usage.

```
// Using complex type
class Person()
{
    public string Name;
}

IEnumerable<Person> myEnumerable = new List<Person>();
this.myEnumerable.OrderByDescending(person => person.Name)

// Using value type
IEnumerable<int> ints = new List<int>();
ints.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```